# Is it possible to compare two booleans with an &&?

Tags: android

In my project I have to see if two Booleans are set to true. I can't put an && in the if statement because it results in errors. Is there a way to check if two Booleans are true in an if statement?

EDIT: to the request to see the code:

```
//Declarations at top of code
    Switch longplay_button;
    boolean longplay_buttonChecked = false;
    boolean normal_buttonClicked = false;


      } else if **(normal_buttonClicked = true**  && longplay_buttonChecked = false) {
                    inactiveButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_default);
                    inactiveButton.setEnabled(false);
                    meme_Sound_Media_Player.release();
                    memeSoundMediaPlayer.start();
//All within on click listener. If button is pressed and longplay switch isn't play shorter sound.

                }
```

Error is ****bolded**** it's just a red underline in the IDE

Comment: Will you please share the code that you are trying and is not working?  Also, please share the error that is being reported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
boolean b1 = true;
boolean b2 = false;

if (b1 && b2) { } else { // this will execute because b2 is false }
```

All are valid.

If you meant `Boolean` (with Uppercase), the same is kinda true:

```
Boolean b1 = true;
Boolean b2 = false;

if (b1 && b2) ...
```

The only thing to keep in mind is that `Boolean` with upper case, is a reference to an Object, not a primitive, so it can be `null`. E.g.:

```
Boolean b1;


if (b1) { } // this will crash with a Null Pointer Exception because b1 is not assigned/initialized.
```

#### UPDATE

Simply for reference and because the OP is unsure, [here's](https://programming.guide/java/primitives-vs-objects-references.html) a good definition of a primitive vs. object in Java.

> You could view primitive values as actual data, and objects as containers of data. If primitive values where atoms, objects would be molecules.

I'm not sure if that's the best description I read, but basically:

int, short, boolean, etc. are all primitives, and are not stored in the HEAP memory (upper); they are safe because they can never be null.

```
boolean b1; // false by default
boolean b2; // false by default
int x; // 0 by default
```

Whereas `Objects` are stored in the memory HEAP and Java keeps a reference (pointer) to where in memory those objects are.

```
String helloString; // this is NULL at this point
```

To understand that, you need to read about Nullability in java. Essentially, the above string is going to be NULL until I create an instance of it. For strings this is easy:

```
String hello = "Hello!";
```

Now `hello` (the variable) is pointing to an area in memory where the string `Hello!` is stored.

And to end this, Java has various non-primitive versions of:

```
int -> Integer
boolean -> Boolean
double -> Double
```

etc.

There are use cases for these (although normally you should *always try to use the primitive when possible*).

On the other hand, certain objects are never primitives (in Java):

`String`, `Date`, etc.

So you have to create instances by calling their constructors. Now i'm off-topic :)

Comment: Sorry if I sound like noob what exactly do you mean by primitive type? Is that the same type of data like integers and strings? Also how does your first block still run if b2 is false, then wont it not execute because both booleans are not true

Comment: Absolutely no worries; we are all newbies in something at any point in our lives, nothing to be ashamed of; for this particular case, what you're asking is *really basic* in the Java language (and many others), so my best advice to you is to peek at what the difference is (because in Java in particular, this is _very very important_): E.g.: https://programming.guide/java/primitives-vs-objects-references.html

Comment: That explanation clarified it well thanks man. Disregard my second question in my first comment I understand your code now.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for sharing the code.

The specific error you're bumping into is because you are trying to compare with just `=` instead of `==`.  A single equal sign (`=`) is used for *assignment* and two equal signs (`==`) are used for *comparison*.

So, instead of:

`else if (normal_buttonClicked = true && longplay_buttonChecked = false) {`

you would have:

`else if (normal_buttonClicked == true && longplay_buttonChecked == false) {`

Those boolean phrases can be simplified, though.  So, if you wanted to get even fancier, you could have something like:

`else if (normal_buttonClicked && !longplay_buttonChecked) {`

However, keep in mind the nullable issues that Martin mentioned!

Comment: ahhhh this makes a lot of sense thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
if (normal_buttonClicked && longplay_buttonChecked){ 
    //if both are true it will enter in this block
}
```